# J2SE JNDI : Issue starting standalone JNP server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jndi

I am trying to start a JNP server, using instructions from http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074186/jndi/j2ee-or-j2se--jndi-works-with-both.html .

I then created some directories to store my scripts and libraries to be able to have the standalone JNP server.
The following is the directory hierarchy.

bin

```
-jnp-start.bat
-jnp-start.sh
```

conf

```
-log4j.properties
-jndi.properties
```

lib

```
-jbossall-client.jar
-jboss-common-core.jar
-jboss-logging-spi.jar
-jboss-remote-naming-1.0.1.Final.jar
-jnp-client.jar
-jnpserver.jar
-log4j.jar
```

logs

The jndi.properties has the following :

```
java.naming.provider.url = jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming
```

The jnp-start.bat has the following :

```
@ ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET JNDI_HOME=..
SET CLASSPATH=%JNDI_HOME%
FOR /R %JNDI_HOME%\lib %%A in (*.jar) do (
SET CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%A
)
SET JVM_ARGS=-Djava.library.path=%JNDI_HOME%\lib
ECHO "java %JVM_ARGS% -classpath %CLASSPATH% org.jnp.server.Main"
java %JVM_ARGS% -classpath %CLASSPATH% org.jnp.server.Main
```

When I run the script this the output I get:

```
 D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\bin>jnp-start.bat

"java -Djava.library.path=..\lib -classpath ..;D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\lib\jboss-     common-core.jar;D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\lib\jboss-logging-spi.jar;D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\lib\jboss-remote-naming-  1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\ComzAfrica\xtracash\jndi\lib\jbossall-client.jar;D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\lib\jnp-client.jar;D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\lib\jnpserver.jar;D:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory\jndi\lib\log4j.jar org.jnp.server.Main"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jnp.server.Main.getNamingInstance(Main.java:403)
    at org.jnp.server.Main.initJnpInvoker(Main.java:461)
    at org.jnp.server.Main.start(Main.java:422)
    at org.jnp.server.Main.main(Main.java:113)
```

What could be the problem causing the NullPointerException ? or what do I need to change ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must ensure jndi.properties in the root of the classpath.

Second, delete "java.naming.provider.url = jnp://localhost:1099" line in your jndi.properties file.